# Rails 3 - How to change attribute in controller before update save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

So, i have form that updates a record in the database.  In my controllers `update` action i want to change a value to something if another one of the values is `Estimate`.  Maybe this will make more sense...this is what i'm trying to do.

```
def update
    @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
    if @invoice.update_attributes(params[:invoice])
        if@invoice.status == "Estimate"
            # if the value of status is Estimate then change the
            # value of estimate_sent_date to the current timestamp
        end
        redirect_to invoices_path
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

The only values of the form that i'm concerned with are `status` and `estimate_sent_date`.  Mostly, i'm just not sure how to change the value of `estimate_sent_date` and save that record.

Also, should i save everything and then do a separate call to save the `estimate_sent_date` or just save it all at once?  I guess i could change the value of `estimate_sent_date` before calling `if @invoice.update_attributes(params[:invoice])`, couldn't i?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ryan Bigg says, state machine does work here.  An alternative solution is to use a `before_save` callback on the Invoice model, like so:

```
before_save :set_sent_date

def set_sent_date
  if self.status_changed? && self.status == "Estimate"
     self.estimate_sent_date = Time.now
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  This may be the best route for me. The `state_machine` gem looks interesting but it may be more than i need since this is just a personal application anyway.

Comment: Yep, state_machine can be overkill sometimes.  Learn more about active record callbacks here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: [`Workflow`](https://github.com/geekq/workflow) is probably the 'new-cool' in state machine gems. It seems to be actively maintained vs `state_machine` which appears abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

I would move this kind of business logic in your Invoice model. This is a typical use case for  a :before_save callback

Comment: Please provide examples when answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to re-invent a state machine here. I would recommend looking into the `state_machine` gem and then using it to implement an event that happens after an invoice transitions to the 'estimate' state, placing this inside the `state_machine` definition which would go inside your model:

```
after_transition :to => :estimate do |invoice|
  invoice.estimate_sent_date = Time.now
end
```

Comment: I'm guessing i would put that in my model?

Comment: yes, this goes in the model.  good practice to keep the controllers skinny!

Comment: Updated answer to reflect that the code should go into the model.